# HomeKit is unable to recognize when people are home following update to iOS 17

Tags: bug, homekit

After updating to iOS 17, HomeKit fails to recognize when people are home and as a result sends endless motion notifications.

How do I get HomeKit to recognize when people are home? (Updating my ATV+ and HomePods has not improved the situation.)